might (typical events from the past)

In those days, children might be forced to work in mines.

[From The Wisdom English-Japanese Dictionary.]
Does this sentence state something that actually happened in the past?
According to the dictionary, might indicates a typical example from the past, but I never learned this usage of might in school.
[Edit] I have consulted many dictionaries (Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, etc). It seems that The Wisdom English-Japanese Dictionary is the only dictionary that says "might" could be used to indicate 'typical events from the past'. (But, I do not own the OED. It is prohibitively expensive!).

No: "might" is the preterite (past) form of "may". It typically indicates epistemic modality, in this case possibility.

Actually the sentence implies that some children, at the time, were forced to work in mines.

There is no implication that children were forced to work in mines. "Might" expresses non-factuality, thus "might be forced to work in mines" presents it as a possibility (not a certainty, as in ... "were forced to work in mines").

@BillJ - Surely, the point of the sentence is that it was a real possibility for some children.

@KateBunting That's what I said - a possibility.

There is the implication (a correct one) that some children were forced to work in mines.

Going to work on the bus last year, I might see my friend's mother. This means (does not 'imply') that, at least once, but probably more, I actually did see her.  Might is also used, though mainly in literary contexts, to refer to habitual activity: In those days we might go for a walk in the woods.  The English Verb, by F. R. Palmer (2nd edition)

@BillJ - It was more than a 'possibility' for the ones that had to go down the mine. So 'might' has the 'habitual' meaning.

@MichaelHarvey It's not more than a possibility. "Might" is used primarily for modal remoteness and in backshift, not here for habitual actions.

I maintain, still, that 'In those days, children might be forced to work in mines' can be re-written, with no change of intended meaning, into 'In those days, some children were forced to work in mines.'

The modal auxiliary "might" is simply not used to express 'habitual action'. The sentence as it stands uses "might" to convey its usual modal meaning of possibility.

Typical is probably too strong, suggesting a habitual activity rather than a situation that occurred for some children.

@BillJ So you think the sentence means In those days, children might have been forced to work in mines, right?

I agree with @Bill J.
Might has the sense of possibility.
To say that that actually happened, we could use were:

In those days, (some) children were forced to work in mines.

Would be has less certainty than were:

In those days, (some) children would be forced to work in mines.


Might also expresses habituality.

@MichaelHarvey Not here it doesn't. Btw, drive-by downvoting is unreasonable.

I disagree, @BillJ. It does imply only possibility in a sentence like, In those days, children might grow up to walk on the moon: none of them did, but it wasn’t an impossible prospect. But in the context of the OP’s example, the meaning is that the possibility (here of conscription into mining) was much more “real” because it was not an atypical fate, it was something that did happen to children similarly situated.

@BillJ - Are you suggesting I downvoted this answer?

@PaulTanenbaum - I'm not sure what you mean. In those days, children might grow up to walk on the moon: - not in the same era that children went down mines; no Apollo rockets in those days.

@PaulTanenbaum The modal auxiliary "might" is simply not used to express 'habitual action'. The sentence as it stands uses "might" to convey its usual modal meaning of possibility.

@BillJ, do I understand you to mean that you would dispute that the sentence When I was a child I might visit my grandparents once a week means something like As a child I visited my grandparents a lot. How often? Oh, I don't know, maybe weekly?

@BillJ - so you disagree with this? Might is also used, though mainly in literary contexts, to refer to habitual activity: In those days we might go for a walk in the woods. The English Verb, by F. R. Palmer (2nd edition)

@Seowjooheng Singapore. Thank you very much. I suppose In those days, children might have been forced to work in mines is better. What do you think?

@Kaguyahime, you're welcome.  I'll let the rest of the users comment on this.
